Plotting at bottom of chart like basic Volume indicator
How do I plot on the bottom of the chart like the basic volume indicator does? I want to stack up some dots that will light up if certain conditions are met.
Thanks

You cannot do that. The volume indicator is a special one.
You can only have one line of shapes at the top/bottom of your chart using location.top and location.bottom parameters.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plotshape(true, "", shape.circle, location.top, color.green)
plotshape(true, "", shape.circle, location.bottom, color.red)


